# ASP.NET - encrypting confing sections - ProtectSection - RSAProtectedConfigurationProvider

Tags: asp.net, configuration, web-config, rsaprotectedconfiguration

I am developing a web application using vs2008 and used two accounts on Vista 64 bit - the original first admin account after the Vista install and now a power user account.

I forgot what I did, but when I run SectionInformation.ProtectSection (System.Configuration) under the original account, the encryption of the config section works and reading from it does too.

When I run it under the power user account, it gives me an error - Object already exists and I can't read from it - I get: The RSA key container could not be opened.

How do I give the power user permission run ProtectSection?  Using RSAProtectedConfigurationProvider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved - someone else had the same exact problem, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42115/app-config-connection-string-protection-error), but in addition, some machineKeys did not have modify permission and it was a pain to delete them.  Also, I had to grant other users read rights to the machinekey or the aspnet_regiis grant wouldn't work.  Thanks to MikeScott8.