# Encrypted config file does not work for Windows Service

Tags: .net, app-config

I am encrypting my app.config via the "aspnet_regiis -pef" approach.

Encryption and decryption work fine. If I decrypt the config file, the service runs fine. When I encrypt two sections of the config (via above method), the service refuses to start, w error below.

But at run time, the framework throws a ton of "exception while reading config..." errors (below).

I thought .config encryption was transparent to .NET apps generally? (under IIS, cmd line, etc.)

I can make the error come and go by decrypting: "aspnet_regiis -pdf" and then make it come back via "aspnet_regiis -pef"

The service is .NET 4.6, VS 2015, log4net and nhibernate.

To be clear, the .config is VALID. Here are the steps:

1) Clear, clean, unencrypted app.config: console app runs fine

2) paste in the < configProtectedData> section (required for encryption) , Then use "aspnet_regiis -pef"  (which rewrites the config, if I damage it with the paste above, aspnet_regiis chokes -- if it works, config is valid )

3) Now the app won't run, error below.

4) OK, so I unencrypt via "aspnet_regiis -pdf", re add < configSections> and now the app works fine. (Again, if the xml were damaged, "aspnet_regiis -pdf" would blow up, but it does not, it works fine.)

I can repeat the above all day long.

One thing that I scratch my head over:

When you encrypt using "aspnet_regiis -pef" < configSections>  is lost. aspnet_regiis.exe does not write it out. If you put it in manually after encryption, the System.Configuration module complains that there can only be one section beginning with the reserved "config" keyword.

I am not sure what the inner meaning of that is.

What direction should I go?

```
log4net:ERROR DefaultRepositorySelector: Exception while reading ConfigurationSe
ttings. Check your .config file is well formed XML.
System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Configuration system failed t
o initialize ---> System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Unrecognize
d configuration section hibernate-configuration. (C:\Inetpub\ProofConcept.Service.Se
rver\bin\Release\ProofConcept.Service.Server.exe.Config line 33)
   at System.Configuration.ConfigurationSchemaErrors.ThrowIfErrors(Boolean ignor
eLocal)
   at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.ThrowIfParseErrors(Configurat
ionSchemaErrors schemaErrors)
   at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.ThrowIfInitErrors()
   at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.EnsureInit(String configKey
)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.PrepareConfigSystem()
   at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection(String sectionName)
   at System.Configuration.PrivilegedConfigurationManager.GetSection(String sect
ionName)
   at System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticsConfiguration.Initialize()
   at System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticsConfiguration.get_IndentSize()
   at System.Diagnostics.TraceInternal.InitializeSettings()
   at System.Diagnostics.TraceInternal.WriteLine(String message)
   at log4net.Util.LogLog.EmitErrorLine(String message)
log4net:ERROR DefaultRepositorySelector: Exception while reading ConfigurationSe
ttings. Check your .config file is well formed XML.
System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Configuration system failed t
o initialize ---> System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Unrecognize
d configuration section hibernate-configuration. (C:\Inetpub\ProofConcept.Service.Se
rver\bin\Release\ProofConcept.Service.Server.exe.Config line 33)
   at System.Configuration.ConfigurationSchemaErrors.ThrowIfErrors(Boolean ignor
eLocal)
   at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.ThrowIfParseErrors(Configurat
ionSchemaErrors schemaErrors)
   at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.ThrowIfInitErrors()
   at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.EnsureInit(String configKey
)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.PrepareConfigSystem()
   at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.get_AppSettings()
   at log4net.Util.SystemInfo.GetAppSetting(String key)
log4net:ERROR DefaultRepositorySelector: Exception while reading ConfigurationSe
ttings. Check your .config file is well formed XML.
System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Configuration system failed t
o initialize ---> System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Unrecognize
d configuration section hibernate-configuration. (C:\Inetpub\ProofConcept.Service.Se
rver\bin\Release\ProofConcept.Service.Server.exe.Config line 33)
   at System.Configuration.ConfigurationSchemaErrors.ThrowIfErrors(Boolean ignor
eLocal)
   at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.ThrowIfParseErrors(Configurat
ionSchemaErrors schemaErrors)
   at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.ThrowIfInitErrors()
   at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.EnsureInit(String configKey
)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.PrepareConfigSystem()
   at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.get_AppSettings()
   at log4net.Util.SystemInfo.GetAppSetting(String key)
log4net:ERROR DefaultRepositorySelector: Exception while reading ConfigurationSe
ttings. Check your .config file is well formed XML.
System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Configuration system failed t
o initialize ---> System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Unrecognize
d configuration section hibernate-configuration. (C:\Inetpub\ProofConcept.Service.Se
rver\bin\Release\ProofConcept.Service.Server.exe.Config line 33)
   at System.Configuration.ConfigurationSchemaErrors.ThrowIfErrors(Boolean ignor
```

Comment: its trying to read from decrypted config file.

Comment: @VuralAcar I do not follow, sorry. Note, I updated the OP (and am about to again)

Comment: I think what Viral Acar is pointing out is that the error suggests that there's somehow an unexpected element in the configuration data (`Unrecognized configuration section hibernate-configuration`), which means that the data must have been correctly decrypted.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError  OP expanded to address what you raise.

Comment: Why do you have to paste in the < configProtectedData> section? Did you follow [this guide](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998283.aspx)? If you followed the `Using RSA with a User-level Key Container to Encrypt a Connection String in Web.config` section then maybe windows service does not have access to user-level key container.

Comment: Therefore I would suggest you follow the `Using RSA with a Machine-Level Key Container to Encrypt a Connection String in Web.Config` section that does not require you to edit the config. Encryption key will be placed in LocalMachine store so anyone on that machine can decrypt the config. If that is not an option then try to encrypt the config under the same user that your windows service runs under.

Comment: @pepo That article you site is outdated. From my experience, it is wrong (at least when using .NET 4.6, which is what I am using). To use a machine level key, configProtectedData section is REQUIRED by aspnet_regiis