# "aspnet_regiis -pef " command removes " <configSections>" section of web.config

Tags: asp.net, .net, aspnet-regiis.exe

I am using the following command to use a machine key to encrypt part of my web.config (it is actually an app.config for a .net app, renamed to web.config so the aspnet_regiis will work with it):

```
aspnet_regiis -pef "section-to-encrypt" "C:\inetpub\path-to-web.config\bin\Release" -prov "provider-name"
```

Before running this, I add the section   < configProtectedData>, which seems to be required (to hook "provider-name" to machine crypto, it appears).

Problem: After running the above command, the   < configSections> is removed from the .config file, damaging it.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar issue which I just resolved. If I insert the configProtectedData. section before the configSections section it was wiping out configSections. If I added it after the configSections section it does not.

I'm encrypting a regular web.config file but I don't believe that difference matters.