# How to encrypt config file ? desktop .NET

Tags: c#, wpf

Please give me a working example.
I have already created a topic, but I'm not there who are not helped [How to encrypt app.config?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4330122/how-to-encrypt-app-config). Or am I just not what is not understood.
Once again, I beg you give 100% working example.

I need to encrypt connectString to access the DB mysql.

is an example http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/yougerthen/306132008064100AM/3.aspx.
There are two ways the first I have an error.
Second, I do not understand how to use

Do not write a lot of text, I do not understand very well. I'm Russian.

**UPDATE:**
I decided to use http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.rsaprotectedconfigurationprovider.aspx.

But I have an error: "Failed to encrypt the section 'connectionStrings' using provider 'RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider'. The error message from the provider: The object already exists."

I Create App WPF. Append file app.config.

app.config body:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
    </configSections>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="myconnect"
            connectionString="myConnectString" />
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

What do I do next ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to encrypt app.config?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4330122/how-to-encrypt-app-config) by the same user.

Comment: you just CEP. I already had written. In the last post, I have not helped.

Comment: Google more:) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42115/app-config-connection-string-protection-error

Comment: @Simon, "If you're on Vista or above, make sure you're running as administrator." - is helped me.  but I can not understand how to use it. Is a C # can do that would run from the administrator?

Answer (score 1):

Do this in your installer,

1. rename app.config to web.config.
2. Use ASP.NET way to encrypt the data you want to encrypt.
3. Rename it back to what.exe.config.

Comment: I do not like this option, there must be a normal way.

Answer (score 1):

Best practice is to do it manualy in your settings class: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.rsaprotectedconfigurationprovider.aspx