# Encrypting Connection string is giving strange error in asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, encryption, web-config

I want to `Encrypt` my connectionstring while sending the source code for Viewing purpose. So I am doing something like this below in `Global.asax` file.

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    // Code that runs on application startup
       EncryptConnString();
}

public static void EncryptConnString()
{
    Configuration config = System.Web.Configuration
                                     .WebConfigurationManager
                                     .OpenWebConfiguration("~");

    ConfigurationSection section = config.GetSection("connectionStrings");

    if (!section.SectionInformation.IsProtected)
    {
        section.SectionInformation.ProtectSection("RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider");
        config.Save();
    }
}
```

but at this line `config.Save();` I am getting some strange Error which is below

> An exception of type 'System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException' occurred in System.Configuration.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: An error occurred executing the configuration section handler for connectionStrings.

I am unable to find the reason of it as it is the standard code to Encrypt it. Please suggest what might be the cause

Comment: I believe that you do not have correctly setup the encryption for the connection string. Please consider this answers -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42115/app-config-connection-string-protection-error

Comment: @Aristos:  what kind of setup ? didnt got you

Comment: I have add a link on previous answer, with the details...

Comment: @Aristos: now got it, but where to add this part which will give me rights to access that class `aspnet_regiis -pa "NetFrameworkConfigurationKey" "{domain}\{user}"` ??